# Automatically add data with VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have two sheets.
On the first sheet there are 2 columns: name and date of birth.
On the second sheet in the first column, a drop-down list from the name on the first sheet.

How on the second sheet in the second column automatically add the date of birth of a person??

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)
```

---

for array use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, see the attached sample pict:

```
=filter ( VLOOKUP ( A2:A, filter ( Log!A2:B, Log!A2:A<>"" ), 2, 0), A2:A <> "")
```

Log Sheet

[image]

Working Sheet:

[image]